# GeoServer Proxy Base URL handling of multiple hosts in X-Forwarded-Host Header

Tags: geoserver

I am running GeoServer behind an Apache proxy and want to use the [https://${X-Forwarded-Host}](https://$%7BX-Forwarded-Host%7D) template as a Proxy Base URL as described here: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html

At the moment I am running into the following problem:
The proxy server sets the X-Forwarded-Host header to the correct host, but the
string consists of a comma separated list of hosts and GeoServer does not seem
to be able to work with that or parse it correctly.

The URL that shows up in the capabilities document looks like:

`"https://geoserver.mydomain.at, geoserver.mydomain.at/"`.

Because of that the layers are not consumable.
Any ideas to work around that issue? Unfortunately I do not have access to the the
proxy configuration since it is managed by another department in the organization.

Comment: why not just set it to `https://geoserver.mydomain.at` ? the end point doesn't change does it?

Comment: That is right, the endpoint does not change. But I have the following scenario:

Admin web interface and REST interface "/web" and "/rest" are blocked by the reverse proxy server for security reasons. So when I just set the proxy base URL permanently I cannot open the web admin interface anymore (from inside the company LAN). As soon as you enter your admin user and password on the login page and press login, the page redirects to the domain. Using X-Forwarded-Host header it would be set the base URL to the domain if the header is present, if not present It would use the internal host.

Comment: I just had this issue, but the reason is that GeoServer has two layers of reverse proxy. If GeoServer is sitting behind single reverse proxy, you may try setting proxy base URL as: ${X-Forwarded-Proto}://${X-Forwarded-Host}/geoserver. This will let GeoServer use dynamic URL based on headers. When logining in from inside the server, it will use localhost, so Admin should work. When requesting layers from outside, it will use proxy domain. This is described in the document you cited (Section: Use headers for Proxy URL).